# not returning the firestore database function in node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here is a request to get a key from the cloud functions. I am receiving the key in the console but it is not returning me the firestore database where I am storing the values.

Here is my code:

```
return request(options, function (error, response, body){
  tokenName = body.notification_key;
  console.log('Key: ' + tokenName);       //gives me the key successfully
  return Promise.all([tokenName]).then(() =>{  //this code doesn't run in the firestore functions console. 
    console.log('key name: ' + tokenName);
    return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set({name: name1,token_id: token_id1,notification_key: tokenName,image: image,email: token_email}).then(() => {
      return console.log("Document successfully written!");       
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
  });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be much simpler:

```
return request(options, function (error, response, body){
  tokenName = body.notification_key;
  console.log('Key: ' + tokenName);
  return db.collection('Users').doc(user_id).set({name: name1,token_id: token_id1,notification_key: tokenName,image: image,email: token_email}).then(() => {
    return console.log("Document successfully written!");       
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    return console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
  });
});
```

That still doesn't write a result to the response though, but it's hard to be certain what the result is meant to be from what you shared.

I'm not sure why you're trying to use `Promise.all()` here. I highly recommend that you read some tutorials on promises before continuing. This [blog post explains the basics](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-firebase-apis-asynchronous-callbacks-promises-tasks-e037a6654a93), [this video explains promises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=726GW5bg3OY), as does [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA&t=1s).